# How to call DLL function returing string from Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, excel-addins, vba

I have a compiled DLL coded in C that exports this function:

```
__stdcall const char *GetVersion() {
    return "1.0.2";
}
```

I'm trying to call that function from Excel VBA. I've declared it as follows:

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetVersion Lib "example64.dll" () As String
```

But when I try to call it:

```
Debug.Print(GetVersion())
```

Excel crashes.

I have several other functions working fine that return numbers and such. It's just this one that returns a constant string that is giving me fits. How do I get this to work?

Thanks!

Comment: Read the documentation: [How to: Access DLLs in Excel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb687915.aspx)

Comment: I suggest you to try with [Excel-DNA](http://exceldna.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Getting%20Started) instead